# Add-on SDK: WebDAV upload from addon

Tags: javascript, file-upload, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, webdav

I am trying to upload a file to a WebDAC server. iLocalFile is a reference to a local input file:

```
  var inputStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"]
                    .createInstance(Ci.nsIFileInputStream);
  inputStream.init(iLocalFile, DELETE_ON_CLOSE, 0, 0);

  var oIOService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                   .getService(Ci.nsIIOService)
  var oHttpChannel = oIOService.newChannel(sRemoteFileName, "", null);
  oHttpChannel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
  oHttpChannel.requestMethod = 'PUT';
  oHttpChannel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIUploadChannel);
  oHttpChannel.setUploadStream(inputStream, 'application/pdf', -1);

  var result = '';
  console.log('Upload starting')
  oHttpChannel.asyncOpen(in nsIStreamListener, result);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to implement the nsIStreamListener. I would be quite happy to thow away the response content if failure/success is still available.

---

### Edit 1: Solution

As per the selected answer with the following modification:

```
  var inputStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"]
                    .createInstance(Ci.nsIFileInputStream);
  inputStream.init(iLocalFile, -1, 0, 0);
  xhr.send(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your WebDAV server is OK with just put (sans locks)...

I'd just use **`XMLHttpRequest`**, as it provides a higher-level API than raw streams (and also avoids some performance/snappiness pitfalls). Just prepare use something like `xhr.send(File(iLocalFile.path))`.

If you still want to use raw channels and a stream listener:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
let listener = {
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIStreamListener]),
  onStartRequest: function(aRequest, aContext) {
    // request started
  },
  onDataAvailable: function(aRequest, aContext, aInputStream, aOffset, aSize) {
   // responseData. May be called multiple times!
   // You probably need to buffer the data from the input stream
   // if you're interested in the response text and manually convert
   // it afterwards.
   // E.g. wrap in nsIBinaryInputStream and .readArrayBuffer()
   // + TextDecoder in onStopRequest.
  },
  onStopRequest: function(aRequest, aContext, aStatusCode) {
   // request done. aStatusCode is an nsresult, not the http code ;)
   //You may want to check this with Components.isSuccessCode
  }
};
```

Where `aRequest` is the original or redirected channel QI'ed to `nsIRequest` (you can QI it to `nsIChannel`, etc. again).
And where `aContext` is the context argument (2nd) passed to asyncOpen. Since we're at it: You cannot really pass a string there. `null` would be OK (let your listener keep track of stuff).